# Teamcity + Gerrit -> Changes are not build (displayed as Pending changes)

Tags: git, teamcity, gerrit

I've setup Teamcity to act as a build server for my gerrit commits and Verify them with +1/-1! The Problem is, the Commits are Displayed as Pending and are not build automaticaly!

I've set-up my Git VCS with following Branch specification:

```
 +:refs/heads/master
 +:refs/changes/*
```

And I've also added a VCS Trigger with following:

```
 Trigger a build on each check-in = true

 Branch filter:
    +:refs/changes/*
```

Comment: did you try to add triggers?